# XCode does not want to use my Developer Certificate since I have used my Distribution Certificate !

Tags: xcode, certificate, distribution

I have just uploaded an app to the App Store. For this purpose, I used the Distribution Certificate.

Since then, I cannot switch back to my Developer Certificate when trying to sign the code. I only do Project Settings > Code Signing. My Developer Certificate is visible but when signing it does not show up. XCode only uses the Distribution one.

Did you face the same issue ?

Of course, I am going to try to generate a new project... Those tools drive me crazy.

Apple92

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the active scheme to debug rather than distribution.

Comment: I only have debug and release. I do not have "distribution". Where can I change this ?

Comment: This will most probably fix your problem. If it does can you please mark this answer as correct? This is what you should do. In your project click on the app project setting at the top of the folder list. Then go to the Build Settings tab and in the search bar search code signing identity and open up the expandable tray then change the value next to Any iOS SDK under both debug and release to iPhone Developer. It should be the 2nd option. I hope this helps.

Comment: Make sure the value next to Code Sign Identity, Debug, and release is set to don't code sign.